# Uma variavel no meu while não está somando

Tags: python, lógica

Sou nova em Python e estou tentando fazer um jogo da velha já tentei de todas as formas arrumar esse erro e não consigo, então peço ajuda a vcs meus consagrados! A minha função jogar tem um while que tem que para quando vez for 9 (que no caso dá velha) ou alguma jogador ganha. Okay! mas o meu while está em loop pq a vez não está contando mais 1. Me ajudem, por favor. Desde já obrigada!

```
import os,time

matriz = []
def jogar(matriz):
    x = "X"
    vencedor = False
    vez = 0

    while (vencedor != True) or (vez <= 9):
        # Pedi para o usúario a escolha
        escolha = int(input("Digite um número para a sua jogada "+x+ ": "))

        #verificar se a escolha é de 1 a 9
        if (escolha > 0) and (escolha < 10):
            #Primeira Linha da matriz
            if (escolha > 0) and (escolha < 4):
                linha = 0
                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz
                if matriz[linha][escolha-1] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-1] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-1] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()
                    vez = vez + 1

            #Segunda Linha da matriz.
            elif (escolha > 3) and (escolha < 7):
                linha = 1

                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz.
                if matriz[linha][escolha-4] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-4] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-4] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()
                    vez = vez + 1

            #Terceira Linha da matriz.
            else:
                linha = 2

                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz.
                if matriz[linha][escolha-7] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-7] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-7] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()
                    vez = vez + 1
            tabuleiro(matriz)
        else:
            print("Opção invalida!")

        # #Chama depois de 1 segundo o tabuleiro  
        # time.sleep(1)
        #os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        #return tabuleiro(matriz)
    else:
        print("Deu velha!")

def verificarVencedor():
   return False 
def preencherMatriz():
    matriz = []
    cont = 0
    for i in range(3):
        coluna = [0]*3
        matriz.append(coluna)

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            cont = cont + 1
            matriz[i][j] = cont
    tabuleiro(matriz)
def tabuleiro(matriz):    
    print("+"*30)
    print(" "*7,"Jogo da velha")
    print("+"*30)
    tabuleiro = '''  
        |     |   
    {}  |  {}  |  {}
    _____|_____|_____
        |     |
    {}  |  {}  |  {}
    _____|_____|_____
        |     |
    {}  |  {}  |  {}
        |     |
            '''.format(matriz[0][0], matriz[0][1], matriz[0][2], matriz[1][0], matriz[1][1], matriz[1][2], matriz[2][0], matriz[2][1],matriz[2][2])
    print(tabuleiro)
    print("Jogador 1: X    Jogador 2: O")
    jogar(matriz)

preencherMatriz()
```

[Link do código no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@BeatrizCarlos/jogoDavelhaTeste)

Comment: Esse é todo o código ?

Comment: Vou manda todo o codigo ;)

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo todo ;)

Comment: Verifique o alinhamento de seus if, me parecem estar desalinhados (pode ter sido apenas um problema ao colar seu código).

Comment: Foi só um problema quando colei o código, sorry. Coloquei o código no Repl.it https://repl.it/@BeatrizCarlos/jogoDavelhaTeste

Comment: o erro ainda continua :(

Comment: @BeatrizCarlos conseguiu resolver ? o Que eu consegui entender é que ele soma o +1 na vez porem o valor da vez está sendo zerado toda vez que você executa o looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma de resolver seu problema mas foi a unica forma que conseguir pensar:

```
import os,time

matriz = []
count_value = 0
def count(count = False):    
    global count_value 
    if count == True:
        count_value = count_value + 1    
        pass   
    return count_value

def jogar(matriz):
    x = "X"
    vencedor = False

    while (vencedor != True) and (count() < 9):
        # Pedi para o usúario a escolha
        escolha = int(input("Digite um número para a sua jogada "+x+ ": "))

        #verificar se a escolha é de 1 a 9
        if (escolha > 0) and (escolha < 10):
            #Primeira Linha da matriz
            if (escolha > 0) and (escolha < 4):
                linha = 0
                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz
                if matriz[linha][escolha-1] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-1] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-1] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()     
                    count(True)               

            #Segunda Linha da matriz.
            elif (escolha > 3) and (escolha < 7):
                linha = 1

                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz.
                if matriz[linha][escolha-4] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-4] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-4] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()   
                    count(True)                 

            #Terceira Linha da matriz.
            else:
                linha = 2

                #Verifica o campo já foi preenchido e insere na matriz.
                if matriz[linha][escolha-7] == "X" or matriz[linha][escolha-7] == "O":
                    print("Esse número já está preenchido!")
                else:
                    matriz[linha][escolha-7] = x
                    vencedor = verificarVencedor()  
                    count(True)                 
            tabuleiro(matriz)
        else:
            print("Opção invalida!")

        # #Chama depois de 1 segundo o tabuleiro  
        # time.sleep(1)
        #os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        #return tabuleiro(matriz)
    else:
        print("Deu velha!")

def verificarVencedor():
    return False 

def preencherMatriz():
    matriz = []
    cont = 0
    for i in range(3):
        coluna = [0]*3
        matriz.append(coluna)

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            cont = cont + 1
            matriz[i][j] = cont
    tabuleiro(matriz)

def tabuleiro(matriz):    
    print("+"*30)
    print(" "*7,"Jogo da velha")
    print("+"*30)
    tabuleiro = '''  
         |     |   
      {}  |  {}  |  {}
    _____|_____|_____
         |     |
      {}  |  {}  |  {}
    _____|_____|_____
         |     |
      {}  |  {}  |  {}
         |     |
            '''.format(matriz[0][0], matriz[0][1], matriz[0][2], matriz[1][0], matriz[1][1], matriz[1][2], matriz[2][0], matriz[2][1],matriz[2][2])
    print(tabuleiro)
    print("Jogador 1: X    Jogador 2: O")
    jogar(matriz)

preencherMatriz()
```

Criei uma função só pra fazer o contagem de forma global.

> Também fiz algumas correções na sua lógica onde em vez de `or` era pra ser `and` e e o comparador de `<= 9` deveria ser `< 9`.

Testa ai e veja se funciona, pelo que entendi seu projeto ainda não esta acabado.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada! Mas houve um pequeno erro, quando sai do while ele print "Deu velha" algumas vezes. Tem como me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: @BeatrizCarlos eu agora estou longe do PC, só devo chegar em um amanhã mas olhando novamente o código, percebi que o alinhamento do else que imprime essa informação, está alinhado com o while ,  creio que o odeial seria criar um IF após o while pra validar se ele ganhou e o else como já está.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, muito obrigada por ter me ajudado!